# Id of Static Resource is being changed on Replace

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-portal, customer-community

I am using a Static Resource (type html) in community header html file for displaying a message and i am using IFRAME to this. This message would change from time to time, but every time I replace the Static Resource, the Id in url being changed. So is there any way to replace doc without id being changed?

```
   <div>
    <p ><iframe src="" align="right" width = "620"height="70"></iframe></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL of a static resource includes the timestamp that the static resource was last changed at. This is generally helpful because it ensures that the browser presents the latest version of the static resource rather than a cached copy of an earlier version. Adding the right timestamp is handled automatically in Visualforce via the [$Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_resource.htm) global e.g. `{!$Resource.YourStaticResourceName}` but I presume in your case that is not available to you.

When a static resource is requested a later timestamp can be used that results in the latest version being returned. This avoids the need to know the timestamp but means the static resource will always be fetched from the server rather than cached because the URL will be different on every request.

Knowing this and the general pattern of a static resource URL, JavaScript can be used to add the timestamp and so deliver the latest version of the static resource:

```
<iframe id="messageIframe" src="" align="right" width = "620" height="70"></iframe>

...

<script>
document.getElementById('messageIframe').src = ''
        + '/resource/'
        + Date.now()
        + '/YourStaticResourceName'
        ;
</script>
```

Ensure that the JavaScript is at the end of the page so that the DOM is complete before the code executes.